# Java : Generating OTP for Auth

Tags: java, security, authentication, one-time-password

Need some basic requirement (size + security) an OTP should comply to. For our application, we are trying to implement the OTP based auth for verification of handphone numbers.

Thank you in advance for your help.

regards,
Manjunath

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you are asking how to implement OTP.
Well, I very much recommmend not to reinvent the wheel. 
You should use [HOTP](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4226.txt) TOTP.

FOr both algorithms there are a bunch of apps for any smartphone around.
So you do not need to send the OTP values via SMS.
Thus, you just need to implement the algorithm in your application.

You could also use a ready made backend system like [privacyidea](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6238.txt) and only pass the username and OTP/password to this backend for verification.

Kind regards
Cornelius

Comment: thanks a lot for your inputs. Will Go through these.